# activity A should be closed after ActivityB but sometimes stays

Tags: java, android, android-intent

It's a bit weird but maybe someone has an idea.

Activity A opens Activity B. In Activity B i press a button and it should be closed

returning to Activity A and then close it as well.

However, sometimes (1 to 7 times maybe) Activity B closes but Activity A remains.

**Activity A**

```
public void Foo() {

    if (bIsVerifyClicked)
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(ActivityA.this, ActivityB.class);
        startActivityForResult(intent, 1000); 
    }
    else
    {
        setResult(RESULT_OK);
        finish();
    }

}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
Log.d(Logger.TAG, "=============requestCode: " + requestCode + " resultCode: " + resultCode);
    if (resultCode ==  RESULT_OK)
    {
        setResult(RESULT_OK);
        finish();
    }

    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

**Activity B**

```
mNextButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Log.d(Logger.TAG, "ActivityB ==== finish()");
        setResult(RESULT_OK);
        finish();
    }
});
```

i thought maybe there is a memory leak in Activity B and thus the onResult get lost or something,

but it's java and i don't see anything strange.

do you have any lead what should i look for?

or how can i better debug this?

Comment: Do you see the `Log.d` line of your `Activity` `A` when it doesn't close but should?

Comment: hard to tell because it happens when the device is not connected to my DDMS in eclipse

Comment: For debug purposes you might add a `Toast` or a `Dialog` to show you've reached the `onActivityResult()` callback.

Comment: **"...it happens when the device is not connected to my DDMS..."** : So immediately connect it and check logcat. Unless your device is doing a whole load of other stuff the logcat buffer won't be overwritten immediately.

Comment: but i see the loagcat buffer only when attached to the app process, no?

Answer (score 0):

I am not able to figure out the exact issue.

But in your code i can see  onActivityResult() of **Activity A**, no need of

```
setResult(RESULT_OK);
```

You can directly finish() activity A.

Comment: it's for closing the activity which called Activity A (recursively)

Comment: If you start ActivityB from  ActivityA using startActivityForResult() then you have to use setResult() in ActivityB  to close it and the result code will come back to ActivityA.

Checkout this document http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#StartingActivities

Comment: I didn't get your comment. there is Activity C which opened Activity A with startActivityForResult() then I have to use setResult() in ActivityA